# 500 Internal Server Error when connecting to MySQL with Flask

Tags: python, mysql

I am starting off with Flask by following this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972

The source code for the tutorial is at: https://github.com/jay3dec/PythonFlaskMySQLApp---Part-1

The code works when I remove the following lines

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'jay'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'BucketList'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
```

However, when those lines are there, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. When I run MySQL I see the BucketList data was already created. What is causing this error?

Comment: Did you verify that you can connect as user `jay` with password `jay` on `localhost:3306` using the command `mysql -u jay -p jay -h localhost -P 3306` and you were able to run `use Bucketlist;`?

Comment: I'm guessing you assumed that the app will create the DB, table and user data. You have to create them manually before you can run your app.

Comment: oh I see. I changed the .py file to username as root and my own password. It works now. However, on `showSignUp` when I enter the username, email and password and then Sign Up, I can't go to the next page

Comment: Did you create the stored procedure `sp_createUser` on the database? You can only go to the next page when both stored procedure and `tbl_user` are present

Comment: it says `sp_createUser` already exists

Comment: How about `Bucketlist.tbl_user`?

Comment: Is `sp_createUser` in `Bucketlist` DB or in `mysql` db?

Comment: It seems you created `Bucketlist` DB but you created both `tbl_ser` and `sp_createUser()` in `mysql` DB. You should `use Bucketlist` before creating these 2 objects.

Comment: I don't understand. I just followed the steps in the tutorial. I created the BucketList database, then the `tbl_user` table and then the stored procedure

Comment: You did. But you probably created both `tbl_user` and `sp_createUser` outside of `BucketList`. Run these command in `mysql`, `use BucketList; show tables; show procedure code sp_createUser`.

Comment: I see `tbl_user` when I type `show tables`. When I type `show procedure code sp_createUser`, I get `'SHOW PROCEDURE|FUNCTION CODE' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with '--with-debug' to have it working`. When I type `show create procedure sp_createUser;`, I see the code that was used in the tutorial

Comment: Did you run it while in `BucketList`? I wanted to make sure you are seeing them in `BucketList`.

Comment: Can you also list the content of `tbl_user` to see if it actually saved your previous attempt to register?

Comment: yes, I ran those commands after typing `use BucketList`. when I type `select * from tbl_user`, I do see 5 rows containing the user_id, user_name, user_username, and user_password

Comment: So it was working all along. Cheers.

Comment: No, because on the `showSignUp` page when I enter the username, email and password and then Sign Up, I can't go to the next page

Comment: Is it throwing a `500 Internal Server` error as well? If not, is it throwing a `40X` or a `30X`?

Comment: It is logging in the console `console.log(error);`. You seriously need to look at your console log.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using apache server, Check error log of apache to see the actual error

Comment: I'm not using apache server. I'm using ubuntu

Comment: @user5739619 If you're running apache sever in Ubuntu, check the error log of apache server running in Ubuntu.

Comment: look for the permission of your script if it is set to executable

Comment: @user5739619 - check the flask log.

Comment: where is the flask log? The script I'm running is just a .py file

Comment: @user5739619 - did you verify your DB? Check my comment on your post.